# i have this error:( raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: )

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

element = wait.until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//a[@class="nop btn g dl _open_window"])[1]')))

element.click()

Answer (score 1):

```
element = wait.until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'(//a[@class="nop btn g dl _open_window"])[1]')))
```

Comment: please explain your answer.